# Looking for a word to describe an independent contractor's workers

Tags: single-word-requests

In a contract I am trying to describe the workers that an independent contractor will supply my company when required to do so. These workers will carry out tasks such as cleaning and driving. I would not describe them as consultants. They are not my employees as they are employed by the contractor. I have thought of:-
Candidates,
Assignee,
Worker
Example of usage:-
"You shall keep record of all the hours worked by each candidate."

Comment: "Crewmember" would encompass any and all workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would call them "**subcontracted workers/labor**" or something similar.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/subcontract

Comment: Or just subcontractors